# Cannot call findChild(QObject, 'child') on QObject. Returns None

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-quick

I've been using QTCreator recently, and I'm in love ATM. Unfortunately, I would like to use it with Python, but I've been running into problems. The biggest problem I have is finding children of my application context returning None.

main.py

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QSize, QObject
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView


LOGIN_SCREEN_SIZE = QSize(640, 350)


def main():
    application = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    login_window = QQuickView()
    login_window.setSource(QUrl('loginscreen.qml'))

    login_window.setMinimumSize(LOGIN_SCREEN_SIZE)
    login_window.setMaximumSize(LOGIN_SCREEN_SIZE)

    login_window.show()

    ## vvvv Returns None ##
    print(login_window.findChild(QObject, 'white_background'))

    # login_window.rootObject().open_main_app.connect(app)

    sys.exit(application.exec_())


def app(username, password):
    print("YAY")

    main_window = QQuickView()
    main_window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

loadingscreen.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

Item {
    id: window
    x: 0
    height: 350
    visible: true
    transformOrigin: Item.Center
    rotation: 0

    signal open_main_app(string username, string password)

    Rectangle {
        id: white_background
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 640
        height: 350
        color: "#ffffff"
        border.width: 0


        Rectangle {
            id: green_background
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 640
            height: 138
            color: "#30945d"
        }

        Text {
            id: login_text
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 640
            height: 124
            color: "#b3d756"
            text: qsTr("LOGIN")
            styleColor: "#f60000"
            style: Text.Normal
            font.bold: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.pixelSize: 112
        }


        TextField {
            id: username_box
            x: 149
            y: 160
            width: 384
            height: 30
            placeholderText: qsTr("Steve")
        }


        TextField {
            id: password_box
            x: 149
            y: 215
            width: 384
            height: 30
            echoMode: 2
            placeholderText: qsTr("qwerty123")
        }


        Label {
            id: label1
            x: 40
            y: 166
            text: qsTr("Username")
        }


        Label {
            id: label2
            x: 40
            y: 221
            text: qsTr("Password")
        }


        Button {
            id: login_button
            x: 548
            y: 308
            text: qsTr("Go")

            onClicked:
            {
                window.open_main_window(username_box.text, password_box.text)

                //Qt.quit() << Only works when launching from C++ file
            }
        }

    }

}
```

white_background isn't the only one I've tested, they all don't work. I cannot understand what the problem is. As a side note, the signal I have in place doesn't send either. I've wanted to try to connect manually, but I can't, because findChild doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of `findChild` does not look for elements by `id`. Instead you should use `objectName` at the *qml* file.

Rewrite your `white_background` Rectangle as:

```
Rectangle {
        id: white_background
        objectName: "white_background"
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 640
        height: 350
        color: "#ffffff"
        border.width: 0
        ...
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I've moved on, but I did try objectName when I was still trying this, and that didn't work either. I swear I put that I did try that in the question, but I guess I didn't, it's been too long.

Answer (score 1):

came across this question while trying to figure out how i can access the value of `TextInput` element from pyqt. tried setting `objectName` as suggested by ismael and it worked. so i guess ismael is right on this.

here is what i tried that worked.

```
@pyqtSlot(result = str)
def saveEdits(self):
    comments = appLabel.findChild(QObject, "commentsTextArea").property("text")
    print(comments)
    return "save edits success"
```

where `appLabel = QQuickView()` and `commentsTextArea` is the `objectName` of `TextInput` element.